# Yii: CGridView fails to render because missing ID field

Tags: yii

In my model, the `id` field is missing and I need to render a `gridview` which failed to render:

```
CException

Property "DocumentRequests.id" undefined.
```

I have a field `document_request_id` instead of `id`

Does the `GridView` work with the `id` field and if so, how can I override it?

Comment: Words without code don't count for much.

Comment: there is no code ... the grid does not work, because i dont have a id column

Comment: All errors produce a stack trace, which tells you where the error happened and what steps led to it. Find it in your error logs, read it, post it here if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian: Sorry, but "there is no code" is just dumb. If there is no code then what exactly are you having trouble with? The weather?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, how to override the `id` field if missing:

```
$data_provider_grid = new CArrayDataProvider($data_provider_grid, array(
            'id' => 'user',
            'keyField' => 'document_request_id',
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => $pageSize,
            ),
        ));
```